# Restore MySQL dump file into database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql dump file named **dblp.sql**
I am trying to restore it to database named **DBLP**

I tried the command:

```
source dblp.sql
mysql -u root -p -h localhost DBLP < dblp.sql
```

And those did not work. I keep getting an error SQL syntax on the second command. And failed to open file on the first command.

Any help would be really appreciated thank you.

Comment: are you doing it after login to mysql terminal ? if yes then its wrong. You need to do it without login to mysql

Comment: yes im doing it through mysql terminal. Sorry I dont really understand how can I do it before logging in? Cause when i open the terminal it always asks for password first.

Comment: Come out of mysql and then on terminal type `cd /folder_name_contains_dump_file` , then run the command `mysql -u root -p -h localhost DBLP < dblp.sql` , it will then ask you password, enter password and it should work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restoring the data using the 'force' flag. One of the server's I helped maintain did not like to restore it's dump'ed data.

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost DBLP --force < dblp.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot DBLP < dblp.sql
```